# Spark is not utlizing any parallization on reduction

Tags: python, scala, bigdata, apache-spark

I'm a newbie to spark. I am using python (pyspark) to write my program. I use `groupByKey` function to transform key-value pairs to key-(list of values) pairs. I am running spark on a 64 cores computer and I try to utlize all the 64 cores by starting the program using the following command.

```
spark-submit --master local[64] my_program.py
```

However, I notice that while executing the `groupByKey` function, only one core is being utilized. The data is quite big. So, why spark doesn't partition it into 64 partitions and do the reduction/grouping in 64 different cores?

Am I missing some important step for parallelization?

The relevant part of the code looks like this,

```
# Here input itself is a key-(list of values) pair. The mapPartitions
# function is used to return a key-value pair (variable x), from
# which another key-(list of values) pair is created (variable y)
x = input.mapPartitions(transFunc)
# x contains key value pair, such as [(k1, v1), (k1, v2), (k2, v3)]
y = x.groupByKey()
# y contains key-list of values pair such as [(k1, [v1, v2]), (k2, [v2])]
```

Comment: how are you loading your data?

Comment: @maasg: I use mapPartitions. After mapPartitions, the resulting data in say variable x is a key value pair, where key is a string and value is also a string. I then use groupByKey to form a key to (list of values) pair, where key is the same key as was in x, and list of values is the list of string values.

Comment: Could you add the code to the question?

Comment: @maasg: Have now added the code.

Comment: still missing the part where the data is loaded.

Comment: @maasg But does that even matter, if you know what the variable x contains? I have not shown the input part because its a bit complex. Is loading of data very important to decide parallelization?

Comment: The data source often determines the initial partitions of the RDD, which will be the basis of parallelization. What's your source of data? A single file, a db, HDFS ?

Comment: My source of data is a text file, but its format is not such as that you can simply just use map function. So, I use the mappartitions function, to return an RDD, which contains key-to-list of value pairs. Can it be that the mapPartitions funtion is bad for parallelization? I use a code similar to what bearitto suggested to this question of mine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741714/how-does-the-pyspark-mappartitions-function-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default parallelism level in Spark is dictated by the configuration option: `spark.default.parallelism`. The default values are: (* from the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior))

> Local mode: number of cores on the local machine Mesos fine grained
>   mode: 8 Others: total number of cores on all executor nodes or 2,
>   whichever is larger

RDDs can be regrouped in more or less partitions using these operations:

```
rdd.repartition(partitions: Int) // redistributes the RDD into the given nr of partitions
rdd.coalesce(partitions:Int) // reduces the number of partitions of the RDD to the given nr
```

Operations that require an internal shuffle often take a `numPartitions` parameters to specify the number of target partitions. After such operation, the RDD will have that new number of partitions.
Let me illustrate that with one example:

Given:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("localFile")  // default nr of partitions. Let's say 2
```

Then:

```
val moreParallelRdd = rdd.repartition(64) // 64 partitions
val onePartitionRdd = moreParallelRdd.coalesce(1) // 1 partition
val sortedRdd = onePartitionRdd.sortBy(x=> sortSelector(x), numPartitions=10) // 10 partitions
```